# Can I return another API's JS promise as my API's response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to send a payment to credit card reader that returns data when the transaction goes through. My use of cloud functions could make this a costly ordeal (based on how to hurried the customer is to swipe their card).

If this isn't possible (maybe because you can convert js to http) no big deal,,, It will a little more work.

Comment: Hi CyberYeti and welcome to SO. If you're new, please make sure you've taken the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please add more details, and the actual code you're referring to. Create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for us to debug and check [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve your question.